# How to filter query by field on nested type/object with mongoose + graphql?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, graphiql

I do not understand how to query by field in nested object as title of this question, with mongoose, graphql, graphiql.... how to write server side code for allow this ?

I setup a GitHub repository for share my code: https://github.com/giovannimanzoni/graphqlTestNested

as github readme, how I can add a code to query results in graphql/resolvers/Users/index.js for query all users that have got a specific network.parentId (graphql/types/Users/index.js) ?

Thanks !

Comment: I find the solution !!!! use 'a.b.c'  :  .findOne({ 'network.parentId' : parentId}).exec((err, res)     I update my repository.